# Multi-column index

Tags: postgresql

I have 4 columns and I would like to match a record if any of the 4 columns match any of an array of values, something like this (syntax is not correct, but this is the idea):

```
SELECT * FROM y WHERE (col1,col2,col3,col4) IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
```

Right now I'm using this syntax:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 y
WHERE
 col1 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
  OR
 col2 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
  OR
 col3 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
   OR
 col4 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
```

I have 4 individual indexes on each column, but I'm wondering if there's a better type of multi-column index I could use.

So two questions:

Is there a better type of index rather than individual ones on each of col1,col2,col3 and col4?

What's the syntax in there where clause?

Answer (score 0):

One index I can recommend in such cases is a [bloom filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bloom.html).

For that, you'll have to use PostgreSQL v10 and install the `bloom` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION bloom;
```

Then you can create a multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON y USING bloom (col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

This index will support your query.

If the `OR` creates a performance problem, try using `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM y WHERE col1 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
UNION
SELECT * FROM y WHERE col2 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
UNION
SELECT * FROM y WHERE col3 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4)
UNION
SELECT * FROM y WHERE col4 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4);
```